# JWPlayer Enable Debug Mode on iOS

Tags: ios, jwplayer

I have searched a lot but I did not find any related post, blog or question about my issue.

I need to check all processes and time of them on JWPlayer when player is loading; Is it possible on iOS?

When I set url of a video (it is stream) the JWPlayer get a long time to be initialized. I want to check what is the process which increase response time.

The JWPlayer version is 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Safari iOS inspector connecting the device to Safari Desktop. then you can check all performances. This is the Apple how-to: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

note: maybe you mean... jwplayer v.7?

**UPDATE:**
using JwPlayer iOS SDK with Xcode you can check che CPU use and processes using Instruments, and Time Profiler tool, ex. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringCPUUse.html

and

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Recording,Pausing,andStoppingTraces.html

Comment: I am not talking web version of JWPlayer; I am using JWPlayer on iOS application and need to check its performance on my app

Comment: I'm sorry for this misunderstanding, so with XCode you can check che CPU use and processes using Instruments, and time profiler, ex. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringCPUUse.html

Comment: I need to check all JWPlayer process and the time of each process takes, I am not sure how is it possible by Instruments

Comment: Yes, you can do it with Instruments. Read 'Profile from XCode' https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Recording,Pausing,andStoppingTraces.html